# How to remove engine oil stain from clothes?

Tags: cleaning, clothing

My new dress is contaminated because of engine oil stain and I try a lot of things to remove that stain like kerosene oil. So tell me how to remove that stains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grease cutter like a Dawn dish soap or a similar product. Not the one used with mechanical dishwasher machines. The type used when washing dishes manually. Make a lather with it and rub it into the stain. Depending on the stain you might have to repeat the process a few times until the stain dissolves or loosens up. Then wash your dress as you would normally.